# Passing optional arguments from makefile to shell script

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile as follows

```
do-something:
    sh ./Scripts/do-something.sh "$(name)"
```

and running it as follows:

```
make do-something name=Foo
```

calls the script as expected.

```
sh ./Scripts/do-something "Foo"
```

**The problem:**

The script also takes a couple of optional arguments, `--noBar` and `--noBaz`, so I can call it like

```
sh ./Scripts/do-something "Foo" --noBar
```

What I want to do is to call the makefile with those arguments and pass them down to the script, e.g.

```
make do-something name=Foo --noBar --noBaz
```

I've got as far as:

```
make do-something name=Foo ARGS="--noBar --noBaz"

do-something:
    sh ./Scripts/do-something.sh "$(name)" $(ARGS)
```

but this seems a bit clunky. Is there a way to do this without the `ARGS=`?

Comment: Are you asking whether there is a way for `make` recipes to refer directly to `make`'s command-line arguments?  No, there is not.  Non-option arguments are specified to be either macro assignments (if they have correct form for that) or the names of targets to build.  There are ways to get at the arguments, such as the `$(MAKE)` and (in GNU `make`) the `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` macros, but these don't really help you.

Comment: Why don't you just `make do-something ARGS="Foo --noBar --noBaz"` and, in your Makefile, `sh ./Scripts/do-something.sh $(ARGS)`? Is it because `name` could contain spaces?

Comment: Just to clarify John's answer: the command line provided to make is completely parsed by make, and any option on that command line which is not a make option will be flagged as an error.  Make is not intended to be a general-purpose scripting language where you can "override" its command line and use it for your own purposes.